# What line of code I remove from a WordPress theme to fix this?

Tags: wordpress

My friend wanted a website for his rap group, so I installed wordpress with the GamePress theme for him since its pretty easy to update and manage with little web design experience

[image]]

He wants that gray part underneath the red menu navigation removed, but doesn't know how, he asked me and i have no clue.. i told him to post a question online but he said its fine like it is but I think it might look better without it and was hoping to figure out how to remove it so I could show him

If you need the source code from the website, it's legendaryhammers.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use web inspector or firebug in your browser. For example, in Chrome right click on the gray bar and click inspect element. This will show you the code and allow you to modify it (although it's not permanent). Once you've found the right modifications, you can change it in the theme file.

Clue - that bar is probably in `header.php`.

Comment: thanks so much!!! within 10seconds problem solved.. greatly appreciate your help!! wow didnt realize it was that simple.. you rock dude thanks so much!

http://oi41.tinypic.com/2uztsmu.jpg = screenshot of problem resolved within 10secs. thanks

im new to stackflow is there anything i need to do to 'close' this question or +1 best answer?

Comment: No problem! To close a question, just choose an accepted answer (as you have). Stack is a great platform for fast answers - I think you'll get a lot from it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

AS s adam suggested, use inspector to see what's happening in the source.

You have there a CSS problem - your  has a dark gray background. Look for `#header` in `/wp-content/themes/gamepress/css/dark.css` and remove line that defines `background`.

A more "pro" way would be to add

```
body #header { background: none; }
```

somewhere in your CSS files, not overwriting the original.